# Icon file for iPhone and iPhone 4 (Does it change?)

Tags: iphone, icons

Hey I was wondering if I have to do anything else with the icon file to make it match the iPhone 4 high resolution retain display? Since you have to do it with the design in the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need one that's twice as wide and twice as tall as the standard 57-pixel one, meaning 114-pixels-square.

Apple lists the sizes and appropriate names in **[Technical Q&A QA1686](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html)**.

Comment: And I should name the one that is 114 pixel: Icon@2x.png ?
And is there any code I need to add?

Comment: @Sweppi No code is required. If it's called "Icon@2x.png" it'll just work.

Comment: @Sweppi Updated to include a better link that has the file names.

Comment: Thanks, Just a quick question about the design of the app. I've named on MyImage@2x.png and one MyImage.png And their both added to my project. Is there any code required for it to work with the artwork in the app or does it change that without any code as it does with the Icon?

Comment: You don't need any code at all. You **do** need to add them to your info.plist, as described on the page I linked to.